# How to find all companies of a certain type in a certain country using Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Imagine, I want to find all companies, which

1. belong to a certain type (like restaurant, gym etc.) and
2. are located in a certain country.

Is it possible to extract those data (names, addresses, locations of all restaurant in the United States, for example) from Google Maps programmatically and without violating their conditions?

I tried to use Google Places API, but the number of the results is limited to 200.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a google-API that will give you "all"

Comment: @Dr.Molle Is there a Google API, which can provide those results for a large area? Like "all restaurants in Berlin"?

Comment: As I said, there is no API that gives you "all" , there are always limits for the number of returned results.